# 1000 watts, 220 volt, 52" length, Coiled Nichrome wire

Tags: resistance, voltage-measurement, thermal, gauge

I need to use Nichrome wire for heating purposes. My heating temperature could be among 200 Celsius, voltage should be 220V, wattage should be approximately 1000 Watts, and length should be 52 inches for this. How can I identify the nichrome wire gauges, and since I am going to use coiled wire in what diameter should the coil be?

Comment: What do you mean by: "and length should be 52 inches for this"? Another question is any restriction in tension of the Nichr wire to be used? By stating watts you mean that you have available 4.545 amps maximum in 220V, or the system it is necessary to consume 1kW?

Comment: I want Longer life Heaters so Tension Strength Should be High and Symbol " refers to Inches, and It is necessary to consume 1KW ie., I need to produce 200 Degree celcius

Comment: Okay, So For 1KW from 220Volts What Guage of Coiled wire Should I Use. My Heating Area should be 52 Inches. Hope You understand my question.

Comment: Still didn't understand because you can produce 200 degr.c even with much lower current using shorter thin wire, than thicker long wire just to pass higher current!

Answer (score 2):

In case that you want to rate your device as  220V/1000W.

The maximum available current is 1000/220=4.54amp. For this applications It is recommended to  use a 80% of the maximum current so finally you have 3.63A. In case of coiled wire half the current.

So you  need a wire with total resistance R=I^2*R or 60,6 Ω. The final resistance due to temperature increase @200oC it is only 2% so we can ignore here.

For this level of power and voltage an AWG 19 to 23 it is recommended, because thinner wires is more sensitive to breakage or burning out to this powers. On the other hand wires with longer diameter it takes longer time to reach the equilibrium temperature, and needs off course  more current.

Looking at the table http://hotwirefoamcutterinfo.com/_NiChromeData_files/1_Amperage.jpg
For 205oC temperature and  current around 3.63 amp, the AWG 20 it is good choice
Now from table http://hotwirefoamcutterinfo.com/_NiChromeData_files/2_Resistance.jpg the total length of the wire should be  L=R/r or 60,6Ω/0.6348Ω per foot = 29meters. But your available space is just 130cm. So you have to coil your nichrome wire.

However coiled wires does not emits temperature to the surround well as strait wires. From practice, and for such diameter of wires  an around 5mm diameter of coil is recommended. But again you need 6,8 meters (assuming you leave 3 times the wire space between each turn!). So you have to re-coil your coil on a proper cement form. You can calculate using simple geometry.

Since you can not control the environment changes as well as to eliminate the risk because of the assumptions and approximations, it is highly recommended to use thermostat. Another recommendation is to drive your heating element using PWM current.
It is easy since your load is ohmic.

Answer (score 1):

If your supply is 220 volts and the power needed is 1000 watts then the current drawn is 4.545 amps. The resistance of the wire is also, by ohms law, 48.4 ohms. This needs to be the resistance when warmed up.

Regards the diameter, this needs to suit your application.

Hopefully, [this](http://www.markssupplies.com/nichrome-wire-and-hot-wire-cutter-parts.html) link will allow you to choose the wire gauge you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If so The Guage 18 is suits if it is straight if I want to use the Coil Type Means How do i Calculate Madam,And If I use 18 Guges means Shall i Use for 52 Inches? and What temperature I get from That? Please help me on this also

Comment: Because you only want 200degC I'd try making a short coiled length and powering it from a DC bench supply to see what temperature it reaches. It's a thermodynamic problem really.